# transactionManager doesn't rollback if one of my spring-jdbc operations fails (after migration from spring-3.1 to spring-4.3.7)

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a java-batch-project where some data-objects (persisted within oracle-db) are modified (several modifications (not at once; because they're too complicated to be stuffed into one db-udpate and because they update several tables).

So far I've used spring-jdbc (including org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager). I had to migrate from 'old' (java6, older libraries (eg spring-3.1,...) and maven) to our 'new way to go' (java8, updated libraries (eg spring 4.3.7,...) and gradle)... and migration was rather a drop-in-replacement (in a gradle-ish way ;-))

(The only code-change so far was that I've changed the way the service-functions were annotated transactional (by adding the propagation **REQUIRES_NEW**) after I've encountered the bug, but this didn't fix it (but I've left it since it seems good style do document the propagation instead of relying on a default.))

But when I've tested the batch I've noticed that (so far without any code-changes)... transaction-handling failed (compared to the 'old' version).

The relevant part of the batches' main-structure is as follows:

---

```
BatchRunner {

    public static int main(int, String) { ... }
    |
    --> calls via injected object
}


@Component
ProcessorService {

    @Override
    public void someProcessingStep()
    |
    ---> selects all 'data-objects'; iterates over them and calls via injected object (DataCalculator.someMethod())
}


@Component
DataCalculator {

    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void someMethod()
    |
    ---> does some calculation; updates; further selects; more calculation; and some final updates to various tables
}
```

---

Whereas `ProcessorService` is not transactional (neither on a class-level nor on a method-level); but the `DataCalculator`'s method `'someMethod'` (which is called (via injected object)) should be... but if for example there are 10 updates made in there... and the 7th fails... usually the programm rollbacked all already done updates... but not with my *spring-4.3.7* migrated version. (Hint: There's only one database/connection involved; this is not an XA-issue).

Of course `DataCalculator`'s `'someMethod'` is a little more complicated and within it it sometimes catches and sometimes catches and rethrows `Exceptions`... but as soon as some `Exception` (or derived class from `Exception`) 'stops' the execution of `'someMethod'` I would expect everything done on my database (within this one 'injected' call) to be rollbacked... and so it was... before migration.

Can you please share some light where I can find my bug (since I don't think this is something framework related... it's rather my wrong way of using it).

If you need further information on this subject, please let me know. (I will update this issue to clarify things; I just wanted to keep the initial post as small as possible.)

Comment: Maybe I should add the following for your better understanding: 

(1) the transaction-boundary is 'DataCalculator.someMethod'; this method is called via spring's injected proxy

(2) within 'DataCalculator.someMethod' are SEVERAL calls to some helper-services and dao-methods implemented as direct-calls. 

if any of these methods fail... the exception is handed back to my transaction-boundary 'DataCalculator.someMethod' which is supposed to be magically committing or rollbacking. <-- This is what's not happening (since I've migrated) anymore.

Answer (score 0):

With `propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` every call of `DataCalculator.someMethod()` will be with a new transaction which will be commited after leaving method.

> if for example there are 10 updates made in there... and the 7th fails...

6 updates will be in 6 different transactions and they will be committed however
a exception will be thrown.

If you want to make all updates together (= in one transaction) - mark `ProcessorService.someProcessingStep` with `@Transactional` (with any propagation) and change a propagation of `DataCalculator.someMethod()` to Propagation.REQUIRES (it's default value).

> **REQUIRED**
> Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.
> **REQUIRES_NEW**
> Create a new transaction, and suspend the current transaction if one exists.

[Propagation docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html)

Comment: Sorry for my bad english... I'll try to explain again (in a little more detail):

Within 'ProcessorService.someProcessingStep' the for example n data-objects are selected; then this function iterates over all of these n data-objects, and for every data-object it calls 'DataCalculator.someMethod'. (The idea is that either everything done for one data-objects is commited or rollbacked.) And if the for example 10 updates are done WITHIN 'DataCalculator.someMethod' the 7th fails... but it doesn't rollback all 6 updates done before. <-- That's the error I've tried to explain.

Comment: The 7th failed update must not rollback 6 updates done before (with propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW). That is expected and right behavior.

Comment: Sorry I have to disagree, because those 10 updates are done WITHIN 'someMethod' - which is the method marked as transactional.

Comment: @ManfredA yes, 10 updates are done WITHIN 'someMethod', but they are done within 10 separate calls of 'someMethod' each of which created new transaction.

Comment: ok, maybe it gets more clear if i explain my example with some actual numbers: 

+ 'main' prepares some stuff and then calls 'ProcessorService.someProcessingStep'

+ within 'someProcessingStep' our 5 data-objects are created...

+ 'someProcessingStep' iterates over those 5 data-objects, and for every data-object it calls 'DataCalculator.someMethod' 

+ within 'someMethod' are 10 updates done to the database; if the 7th update fails... all 6 updates done before are supposed to be rolled back!

Comment: are 10 updates done within 1 call 'someMethod'? Can you show more code of `someProcessingStep()` and `someMethod` methods?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what my real problem was - our integration tests lead me into the wrong direction of thinking that it had something to do with transaction-handling.

The real problem was, that my at first perfectly written DTO's were later on read with some missing columns... and then those incomplete DTO's were overriding the originally stored ones.

(The bug within missing some of the columns was introduced in spring-4.2 where the BeanPropertyRowMapper's initialize() function was changed to handle columns like 'foo_bar_1' different then before.)